# Imaging Raspberry Pi and can't restore. 'Unable to mount foot fs on unknown-block'

Tags: boot, boot-issues, ubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu Mint on my Raspberry Pi and setup everything the way I like. On my Mac, I've gone ahead and created an image via:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk4 bs=1m | gzip > ~/Downloads/MyImage.gz
```

I've also tried with bs=4m, which produces the same result. To restore, I used:

```
gzip -dc ~/Downloads/TimeClock.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/rdisk4 bs=1m
```

I also tried that with bs=4m, which produces the same result.
On the restored SD, upon boot, I get the following error:

```
Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)
```

The cards I'm using are 16GB Samsung Evo SDHC's.
I've tried the following resources to no avail:

- [Renaming 'root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 to 6'](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47539/raspberry-pi-unable-to-reboot-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-2)
- Starting into recovery -- I can't
  hold down shift or press alt-f2. It doesn't do anything.
- Running the
  same process on a couple of USB adapters along with a built-in on a
  Macbook Air.
- Using Win32 Disk Imager
- Using without zipping, both with bs=1m and bs=4m

What's the deal?