# RPi2 : Kernel panic after updating, unable to mount fs on unknown block (179,2)

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot-issues

I had my RPi2 (used as a local web-dev server) crashed after making an update using SSH from a distant computer. During the upgrade, the console started to display there was a bus problem, and after having waited for quite a while I hard-rebooted the Pi, and used a screen to see what happensed Well, I'm stuck with the kernel-panic message mentionned in the title. The Pi is running Raspbian (no NOOBS !).

I found here a post with almost the same issue : [Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,6) running Raspbian on top of NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6). Unfortunately, the solutions proposed don't work for me.

1. I can't enter recovery mode using SHIFT
2. I can edit the cmdline.txt file (either on Windows or Ubuntu), I can replace `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2` by `root=/dev/mmcblk0p6`. However, those changes are not taken into account, and I still have the same message when rebooting.

Just in case, I've testes several power supplies, without success.

How can I force `cmdline.txt` changes to be taken into account ? Is there another way to proceed in order to get my system back ?

**EDIT #1 :**

I've been using an Ubuntu live USB version. The USB device has a capacity of 16 Gb, so has the micro SD used with the Raspi. I used `fdisk` to differentiate both. Here are the results for the Pi micro SD :

```
Disque /dev/sdc : 14,7 GiB, 15811477504 octets, 30881792 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0cf63fa8

Périphérique Amorçage  Start      Fin Secteurs  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1               8192   131071   122880   60M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2             131072 30881791 30750720 14,7G 83 Linux
```

Then, I created a directory `sudo mkdir /media/sdcard/` and mounted the first one : `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/sdcard/`. No surprise here, I get that I already had when inserting the device (automatically mounted by Ubuntu) : the boot part, with `cmdline.txt`, `config.txt`, and the overlay directory.

I am interested as you may have guessed by the files contained by `sdc2`. Hence, I repeated the operation for this volume and I got this :

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /media/sdcard/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Here is what I got after running `dmesg | tail` as suggested :

```
[ 3242.691618] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3538944
[ 3242.691633] JBD2: IO error reading journal superblock
[ 3242.691639] EXT4-fs (sdc2): error loading journal
[ 3518.191904] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3518.191910] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 3518.191913] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 3518.191918] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 36 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3518.191921] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 3538944
[ 3518.191936] JBD2: IO error reading journal superblock
[ 3518.191941] EXT4-fs (sdc2): error loading journal
```

I've already tried to "repair" the faulty block yesterday, but my skills are limited. It obviously didn't work.

**EDIT #2 :**

Ran fsck as suggested. "Reading attempt of a block from the filesystem produced a truncated reading. Execute fsck manually"

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/wpscan$ sudo fsck -a /dev/sdc2
fsck de util-linux 2.27.1
Erreur de lecture du bloc 425984 (La tentative de lecture d'un bloc depuis le système de fichiers a produit une lecture tronquée). 

/dev/sdc2: INCONSISTENCE INATTENDUE ; EXÉCUTEZ fsck MANUELLEMENT.
    (i.e., sans options -a ou -p)
```

Tried to do it manually, but don't know what the best choices are in my case : shall I ignore the error ? shall I force re-writing ? in case of an invalid log for the superblock, shall I erase it ?

Comment: +1 for a well-researched question! More to the topic, do you actually have `/dev/mmcblk0p6`? Since you're not using NOOBS, perhaps your card is partitioned differently.

Comment: Also keep in mind that a failed upgrade can leave you with an unbootable system with incompatible core libraries: be prepared to have more issues when you fix the mounting bug. Do you happen to remember which packages were upgraded?

Comment: so far, I'm only able to see the /boot directory (with a laptpop running Ubuntu Live USB). I've found many other posts about that but I'm stuck with cmdline.txt : don't know how to force it to take into account the changes I made. Unfortunately I don't remember what packages were being updated when the crash happened. Even if I can't reboot, I hope I can recover some files...

Comment: Do you have `gparted`, `fdisk` or a similar tool on your Live USB? Try running it and check what partitions you have.

Comment: yes, thanks. I edited the initial post with all the information I could grab

Answer (score 2):

EXT4 partition on your SD card is damaged to the point it cannot be mounted. If there are files on it that you can't afford to lose, I suggest you make a copy of your SD card with `dd` before proceeding.

The most straightforward solution is to repair the filesystem with `fsck` on your live USB stick:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sdc2
```

If that doesn't work, you have a few options left:

- try to copy the image created with `dd` to another SD card. Maybe yours is faulty
- try to mount the partition without replaying the journal with `sudo mount -t ext4 -o ro,noload /dev/sdc2 /media/sdcard/`. That won't repair anything, but you may be able to recover some files.

Note that the fix suggested in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6) won't help you. It can only fix things for people who do use NOOBS and have their root filesystem on partition 6, while the boot scripts point to partition 2 by mistake. This is not your case.

Comment: You have a bad block on your SD card. Use recovery software to save files from it, then get a new one.

Comment: with sudo mount -t ext4 -o ro,noload /dev/sdc2 /media/sdcard/ I was able to mount the device. However, the interesting directory for me is /var/www/ and it couldn't be read : there was an I/O error ! by the way, the reason why I updated/upgraded the Pi was because Apache didn't behave properly...!

Comment: @Fafanellu Well, I guess this is as far as you can get without professional data recovery services (and there is no guarantee you will get much further with said services).

Comment: of course :( I wonder what caused this bug. I've seen many cases like mine, with a kernel panic after a Raspi upgrade. Maybe I could go a step further if only I could force root=/dev/mmcblk0p6

Comment: @Fafanellu No, that wouldn't help. It can only fix things for people who do use NOOBS and have their root filesystem on partition 6. You don't.

Comment: It's not a software bug.  Bad blocks on an SD card indicate it is worn out or defective.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **recovery.cmdline** file you could try editing it by changing `init=/init` to `init=/bin/sh`. This will skip the init process and boot you straight into shell and from there you might be able to do what is needed to recover.

Comment: I don't have such a file :(