# Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,6) running Raspbian NOT on top of NOOBS

Tags: raspbian, kernel

I tried many fixes, but most of them are for NOOBS Raspbian installations, not for a clan Raspbian installation.

I got the following Kernel Panic error:

```
Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,2)
```

I tried changing the cmdline.txt file as most places suggest:

dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 *root=PARTUUID=eda198d5-**02*** rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

To this:

dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 *root=PARTUUID=eda198d5-0**6*** rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

But I got a new error:

Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,6)

This time ending with (179,**6**)

Comment: duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6

Comment: Those questions are similar, but those fixes do not work on a cleanly installed Raspbian. Only for those who used NOOBS images. Please read the first sentence of the question.

Comment: this answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69124/78211 includes fdisk like in your answer, it is a duplicate imho

Comment: Randomly changing files you don't understand will not help. It is doubtful you have a partition 6. In all likelihood your root partition is damaged. Either restore from backup or re-install. Repairing is rarely successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used @Dr Beco s [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6):

> To deal with the core of the problem (not a workaround), if you can't
>   boot (or you have no "NOOBS"), you need to:
>
> - remove the SD card from your Pi and put it in a card reader in your linux computer.
> - if automatically mounted, umount both partitions. Check the correct device name with `fdisk -l` and `mount -l`. In my example, it is
>     mounted as `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`. So, to unmount, use `umount
>     /dev/sdb1` and `umount /dev/sdb2`. (**BE CAREFULL TO CHECK YOUR
>     PARTITION NUMBER.** "2" here is just MY example).
> - Now you are ready to proceed the check-up with corrections.
>
>   - With `fdisk -l` identify the *DOS* partition and check/fix it with `fsck.fat -y /dev/sdb1` (**Check your correct number**)
>   - Also, `fdisk -l` shows you the `ext4` partition number. Fix it with `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sdb2` (**Check your correct number**)
> - If it automount again, `umount` both again. If not, you are ready to remove from your computer to your Raspberry Pi and turn it on.
>
> If it is just a "block" issue, it will probably be up and running. If
>   the `Kernel Panic` continue, check if the error message has changed to
>   something else. In this case, you should look again for other answers,
>   or maybe consider re-writing your SD Card from scratch.

After that, everything worked fine.
(Note that I returned to my original cmdline.txt configuration)

Comment: Can you please accept your answer to finish the question?

Comment: Sorry, it says that I have to wait 2 days for accepting my own answers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow other's solution with no luck. I had no sudo in the recovery commandline.

I had this error:

> Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,**7**)

What I did:

> 1. **boot raspberry**
> 2. `hold shift`
> 3. do `alt+F2` to go to commandline
> 4. login as `root`:`raspberry` > command line #-sign is visible
> 5. `fdisk -l` to check what partition
> 6. `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/[partition you want]`

hope it helps