# 3B+ Not Booting

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-3b+, boot-issues, vnc

I've had my Raspberry Pi 3B+ for a while now (a couple of months, maybe) and it has always booted just fine, up until this week. I was using the RPi to host my Discord Bot, but now it doesn't seem to boot and/or connect to the network. The device runs on Raspbian through NOOBS.

#### Symptoms

- The device's `PWR` indicator remains a solid red
- The device DOES show `ACT` indicator blinking at startup
- The Two(2) LEDs on the ethernet port light up ever so slightly (no cable)
- The device cannot be found on the network
- VNC Server is not listening for cloud connections

At the time of posting i have read the entire [Pi Not Booting page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) to no avail.

Comment: Does ACT blink randomly, or on/off a countable number of times?

Comment: @Botspot Randomly.

Comment: Try connecting it to a display.

Comment: @Botspot Kernel Panic, says something about a filesystem.

Comment: @Botspot Found [this article](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6) on the error. will check solutions later

Comment: try [reflashing your SD card](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up/3).

Comment: @Botspot No need, below answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> you will need to do a filesystem check & repair:
>
> Start the Raspberry holding the `Shift` key.
>
> Once NOOBS loads, press Alt-F2 to access the recovery command line...
>
> > I had the same problem but with unknown-block(179.7) and the first solution worked fine, just replacing this:
> >
> > `sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/mmcblk0p6`
> >
> > with this:
> >
> > `sudo fsck.ext4 -y /dev/mmcblk0p7`
> >
> > I'm not an expert but hope this could help others.

See more [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6/57139#57139)