# Boot halts on "Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"

Tags: pi-zero-w, boot-issues

On my RPi Zero W I had a kernel panic issue

```
Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,6)
```

but I managed to fix it with the help from the second aswer from this post:
[Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown- block(179,6) running Raspbian on top of NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6)

However now it halts while booting and the last line says

```
Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
```

I checked the filesystem with fsck and it seems ok. What can I do to boot succesfully?

Edit: I should clarify that I don't have NOOBS installed, just Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: I fall to understand why anyone persists in trying to boot NOOBS. Install Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: @Milliways no NOOBS, I'll clarify it in the post

Comment: If you are running Raspberry Pi OS you could not possibly get that error.

Comment: I used the official imaging tool from https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/ and installed Raspberry Pi OS Lite, is that NOOBS?

Comment: @Milliways It better be possible because I'm getting the same error on a new SD card formatted using the Raspberry Pi Imager in a RPi 3+. It worked on second boot though.