# Does Raspberry Pi required official keyboard for wired ones?

Tags: boot-issues, keyboard, raspberry-pi-os

I am having a [kernel error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40854/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block179-6) but even though I have tried many regular wired keyboards, raspberry couldn’t either recognize or power the keyboards. I wonder whether raspberry requires its official wired keyboard for accessing the settings at the boot session.

————————

Edit: I bought an SD card. Then, installed the latest Raspberry Pi. The wired keyboard model that wasn’t recognized during the boot time worked in a fresh boot. As far as I understood that Raspberry Pi does not enable certain parts of it until the boot session is fully complete. But I still wonder how to interfere with kernel issues.

Comment: Is the ACTUAL error secret? How did you setup WITHOUT keyboard?

Comment: I would suggest downloading the latest version of Raspberry Pi OS and install it on a different sd card. Please avoid NOOBS at all cost.

Comment: @NomadMaker I tried buying a brand new SD. Then, installed the latest 32-bit Raspberian as you suggested. It works now. Of course, I'd wish to recover the old one too since it contained important information. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just use a USB SD card reader to read the old card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Pi/RpiOS should work with *almost* any normal USB keyboard.  The potential exception would be keyboards with special features that require specific software/drivers to use -- although even in those cases unless the keyboard is really weird, it would probably still work for basic functionality.  So by "special features" I don't mean that row of controls for play/pause, volume etc. that is fairly common, or LEDS, or even a trackpad, although the trackpad may or may not work (it probably would).<sup>1</sup>

Keyboards don't use a lot of power, so if you have some reason to believe that is the problem, either you have too many other things connected to it, or your power supply is totally insufficient to start with.

---

1. I'm not actually aware of any real examples which would fit this potential exception, so it may well be that it literally does work with all currently available USB keyboards, reason being that the USB protocol for keyboards is standardized, ie., they all work the same way.

Comment: Due to the error I am having, boot is not done completely therefore need to handle my things via a wired keyboard. You say “the Pi/RpiOS should work with almost any normal USB keyboard.” but I didn’t understand whether you are %100 sure about it. I  couldn’t coincide any documentation on raspberry pi website either.

Comment: I'm 100% sure about it -- the only reason I included "almost" is because in theory someone could make a keyboard and sell it specifically with special software to operate it in specific conditions.  Realistically, if you had a keyboard like that you would know it.  It would be something designed for a special purpose and cost a lot more than normal. You could always edit the exact make and model of your keyboard into the question.  *"due to the error I am having, boot is not done completely therefore... "* -> Smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).

Comment: Ahaha, no no not at all :)) All I need is to find a wired keyboard which would help me to apply the steps mentioned in the threaded solution I linked in my question. Last two days, I have tried more than 10 wired keyboards separately for my raspberry pi 3 model b+ but none of them worked. The important part is that the system doesn’t boot properly which may cause the raspberry not recognise the plugged keyboard. But ppl that solves their problem utilizing the solution seems to be successful at their attempt.

Comment: @Nihat You should add all explanation or background information to your question instead of writing comments. It is not normal that a standard USB keyboards does not work. I suggest to boot from a different SD card with a newly installed Raspberry Pi OS (Raspbian) and check if the keyboard works. You can also put the SD card in a Linux system to run `fsck` or to modify files as already written in an answer to the linked question.

Comment: @goldilocks the previous keyboard model that wasn’t working during the boot time worked after having a fresh installation. I guess Raspberry Pi doesn’t enable some parts until the booting is done.